# Timelapse photography with Nikon D3200

Tags: digital, astrophotography, timelapse, smartphone

Does anyone know if there exists an app that acts as an intervalometer for my Nikon D3200 because this DSLR does not have a timelapse feature?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an app, but it is the way many time lapse sequences are done: A wired remote shutter release with an intervalometer built in.

[This one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003Y2YTEE) is designed to work with your D3200.

[image]

Comment: Just a note that you can get unbranded versions of that same device for as little as 8 or 10 £/$/€ I got one for £8.50 inc free postage. Works like a charm.

Comment: It is hard to find the cheapest unbranded versions with the right connector for the D3200.

Comment: Ah, OK. Actually, mine ends in a stereo mini-jack socket to which an adaptor to my D5500's accessory port has been added. According to Nikon http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3200/spec.htm and http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d5500/spec.htm both will take the same MC-DC2 remote, so one can only assume the pinout is the same.